# Failure to push to heroku! (Micharl Hartle Rails Tutorial 3 - Sample App)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railstutorial.org, sqlite3-ruby

Note: Absolute beginner. I note that most answers to similar questions state that SQlite3 does not work with Heroku, and recommend using PostgreSQL. Before making any changes in that direction, I wanted to know if doing so would affect my ability to follow/understand the tutorial?

I'm using the latest gemfile supplied by the author. It was updated on 25th November, 2015. (which is why I'm surprised it contains the SQlite3 gem?)

I'm an absolute beginner, just started learning programming 2 days back.(Explanation along with solution would be much appreciated. (In language that is as simplified as possible) Thank you!

OS: Windows 8.1
IDE: Cloud9
Pushing git to a Bitbucket account.

Bundle install --without production, was successful.
Git initialization and further updates were all without error.

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails',                   '4.2.2'
gem 'bcrypt',                  '3.1.7'
gem 'faker',                   '1.4.2'
gem 'carrierwave',             '0.10.0'
gem 'mini_magick',             '3.8.0'
gem 'fog',                     '1.36.0'
gem 'will_paginate',           '3.0.7'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.10'
gem 'bootstrap-sass',          '3.2.0.0'
gem 'sass-rails',              '5.0.2'
gem 'uglifier',                '2.5.3'
gem 'coffee-rails',            '4.1.0'
gem 'jquery-rails',            '4.0.3'
gem 'turbolinks',              '2.3.0'
gem 'jbuilder',                '2.2.3'
gem 'sdoc',                    '0.4.0', group: :doc

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3',     '1.3.9'
  gem 'byebug',      '3.4.0'
  gem 'web-console', '2.0.0.beta3'
  gem 'spring',      '1.1.3'
end

group :test do
  gem 'minitest-reporters', '1.0.5'
  gem 'mini_backtrace',     '0.1.3'
  gem 'guard-minitest',     '2.3.1'
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg',             '0.17.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
  gem 'puma',           '2.11.1'
end
```

This is the error message that appears at the end of the failed 'git push heroku master' command

```
remote:        Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
remote:        
remote:        /tmp/build_1933bfd027d23ded5c4a036825ecff71/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
remote:        checking for sqlite3.h... no
remote:        sqlite3.h is missing. Try 'port install sqlite3 +universal',
remote:        'yum install sqlite-devel' or 'apt-get install libsqlite3-dev'
remote:        and check your shared library search path (the
remote:        location where your sqlite3 shared library is located).
remote:        *** extconf.rb failed ***
remote:        Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
remote:        libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
remote:        need configuration options.
remote:        
remote:        Provided configuration options:
remote:        --with-opt-dir
remote:        --without-opt-dir
remote:        --with-opt-include
remote:        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
remote:        --with-opt-lib
remote:        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
remote:        --with-make-prog
remote:        --without-make-prog
remote:        --srcdir=.
remote:        --curdir
remote:        --ruby=/tmp/build_1933bfd027d23ded5c4a036825ecff71/vendor/ruby-2.0.0/bin/ruby
remote:        --with-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --without-sqlite3-dir
remote:        --with-sqlite3-include
remote:        --without-sqlite3-include=${sqlite3-dir}/include
remote:        --with-sqlite3-lib
remote:        --without-sqlite3-lib=${sqlite3-dir}/
remote:        
remote:        
remote:        Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_1933bfd027d23ded5c4a036825ecff71/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11 for inspection.
remote:        Results logged to /tmp/build_1933bfd027d23ded5c4a036825ecff71/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/sqlite3-1.3.11/ext/sqlite3/gem_make.out
remote:        An error occurred while installing sqlite3 (1.3.11), and Bundler cannot
remote:        continue.
remote:        Make sure that `gem install sqlite3 -v '1.3.11'` succeeds before bundling.
remote:  !
remote:  !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
remote:  !     
remote:  !     Detected sqlite3 gem which is not supported on Heroku.
```

If the SQlite3 gem is in the ommitted production group, as was the case in the previous exercises, why is this happening only in this excercise?

Comment: What does `git status` says? Run it in your project folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku doesn't support SQLite, you need to switch to PG. Using PG will not affect your ability to follow the tutorial as ActiveRecord abstracts the low-level database-specific commands.

You just need to make sure you are not relying on any feature or behavior that is specific to SQLite.